# Excel VBA For loop in range contains gaps of 0's in sequence

Tags: vba, loops, excel, missing-data

I have isolated the problem and simplified the code to the root cause. More frustrating is that this loop works elsewhere without this error.

If you see the comments in the sequence here, there are 6 cells in the middle of the loop that turn into 0, and then after this 6 cell gap of 0's the loop works. I did use a msgbox to confirm the values were there. For whatever reason rows 130-135 always read as 0 though.

```
For x = 1 To 140
        Cells(3 + x, "AW").Value = 70
        'MsgBox (Cells(3 + x, "AW").Value)
        'MsgBox confirms the correct value
        'rows 130-135 are always empty with 0
Next
```

Any help greatly appreciated - very stumped at such a simple thing!

Comment: There is lengthy code in this file, but after clearing out the entirety of other code, there is a conflict somewhere else which makes the above loop zeros. I will research more and post the complete code along with the conflict.

Comment: your piece of code looks pretty well. May be the problem lies somewhere in your other part of code. We can know where exactly the problem is, if you share other part of code.

Answer (score 0):

it was a simple logical error that was nested inside:

```
For a = 1 To Number_of_CalcRows
Cells(137 + a, "AW").Value = TenkanCurrent 
Next
```

The problem was that I has not declared the TenkanCurrent with a value.